# .split() breaks code

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the code below, the line that is commented out: `var displayPieces = displayWhole.split(" ");` Breaks what happens in .subMenuContent area. If I comment out just that line, it works just fine. Any ideas?

```
$(".subMenuHeader").each(function() {
    var displayWhole = $(this).attr('display');
    //var displayPieces = displayWhole.split(" ");
});
$(".subMenuContent").each(function() {
    $(this).prepend('<div class="subMenuShineLeft"></div>' +
    '<div class="subMenuShineRight"></div>');
});
```

Comment: what error is it giving you in the console?

Comment: Could you post the html or at the least the contents of the `display` attribute?

Comment: What does `displayWhole` contain?

Comment: Did you check your console? Because I got this: _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined_, which tells me that at least one of your `.subMenuHeader` elements doesn't have an attribute `display`. Did you mean `$(this).css('display')`?

Comment: You probably wanted to use this - `$(this).css('display')` - instead. Still it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @JasonP A javascript error would do it.

Comment: If `attr('display')` returns null or undefined then `.split(' ')` would most certainly throw an error.  You need to add a check first before you do the split.

Comment: I voted to put on hold as unclear at first, but then I understood it. Now I've voted to reopen. Sorry.

Comment: There was an empty display that I was using to test aesthetics . . . got by! It essentially was undefined. I've been staring at it too long. Thank you all who commented!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is due to `displayWhole` being `undefined`.

If you want to fetch an element's `display` from its style to check whether it's `block` or `none`, don't use `attr`, use `css`. Like this:

```
var displayWhole = $(this).css('display');
```

The `.attr()` function will fetch you the attributes for an HTML element, alright. But `display` is not a HTML attribute. It is always part of the `style` attribute. Had you used:

```
var displayWhole = $(this).attr('style');
```

Then you'd have the whole `style` as a string, for you to work on.

The `.css()` jQuery function, on the other hand, exists so that you can get the parts of the `style` attribute more easily ;)

Comment: The displayWhole was indeed undefined in one of elements looped through. I have been staring at the code for a while and missed it.